# How to use Base64-encoded DER format in DBT profiles.yml

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, private-key, dbt

I'm trying to configure **DBT** to connect to **Snowflake database** using a **private key in Base64-encoded DER format**. The [documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/connect-data-platform/snowflake-setup) mentions this format, but I'm not sure how to create the key or include it in the **profiles.yml** file.

Could someone provide a clear guide on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to use a Base64-encoded DER format your private key in your DBT profiles.yml.

You should have already generated a private key **private_key.pem**  following this documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth#generate-the-private-key

For **unencrypted** private key:

```bash
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 des3 -inform PEM -outform DER -in private_key.pem -nocrypt | base64 -w0 > b64_private_key.der
```

For **encrypted** private key:

```bash
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 des3 -inform PEM -outform DER -in private_key.pem | base64 -w0 > b64_private_key.der
```

Copy paste the content of the **b64_private_key.der** to your dbt **profiles.yml**:

```yaml
# profiles.yml

my-snowflake-db:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      # ...

      # Keypair config
      private_key: [Paste content of b64_private_key.der file here]
      private_key_passphrase: [passphrase for the private key, if key is encrypted]

      # ...
```

Do a `dbt debug` to verify your connection:

You should be able to successfully configure DBT to use a Base64-encoded DER format private key for Snowflake database authentication.